# hide page wordpress except if you have direct link(how to hide it from indexing, etc)

Tags: wordpress

I have a part of site(one page) that I want to hide and you can access it only if you have a direct link(you don't need to be registered user(public)). So what I need to do to hide it from indexing and stuff like that(I know that is the only way to protect it if page has status public.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using loops everywhere for showing posts.

Add `'post__not_in' => array($post_ID)` wherever you are using the loop in the query.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
  array( 
    ......,
    ......,
    'post__not_in' => array($post_ID)  
     ));
```

This would remove that post from the loop,hence will not show it.